# Get the currently open tabs in Google Chrome via the command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I'd like to write a shell script that automatically transfers all tabs from Chrome to Firefox (by getting the list of tabs from Chrome, and then opening them in Firefox with a script.) In Google Chrome, is it possible to obtain a list of open tabs via the command line?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/issues/447

Answer (score 14):

This question was not answered, solution above is for Chrome Dev Tools where the OP asked in CLI, so this is the solution I've found :

```
strings ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Current\ Session | grep -E '^https?://'
```

Comment: This answer seems not work after Chrome v87. There is no Current\ Session anymore.

Comment: The file is now `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sessions/Tabs*` but there may be more than one file so I assume you'll have to use the file with the greatest number to get the current session tabs.

Comment: I have submitted an edit for `strings "$(find  ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sessions/Tabs* | tail -1)" | grep -E '^https?://'` which will select the most recently created Tabs file (the current session).

Answer (score 14):

For a macOS only solution, you could also use the open-source utility [`chrome-cli`](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli). You can install with Homebrew:

`brew install chrome-cli`

Also, take note of one thing from the README:

> To execute javascript you must first allow it under `View > Developer > Allow JavaScript from Apple Events`.

Here's what it looks like:

```
$ chrome-cli list tabs
[1889] Edit - Super User
[1918] prasmussen/chrome-cli: Control Google Chrome from the command line
[1905] Yotto Winter Mix 19 by Yotto
$ chrome-cli list links
[1889] https://superuser.com/posts/1407956/edit
[1918] https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli
[1905] https://soundcloud.com/yotto/yotto-winter-mix-2019
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a duplicate question (it took a lot of searching to find it, though): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968271/chrome-on-linux-query-the-browser-to-see-what-tabs-are-open

Answer (score 2):

I wish I knew about chrome-cli...

This is also a OSX only solution, i use applescript:

```
function chrome_json_summary() {
local wincount=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get number of windows')
[ "$wincount" -eq 0 ] && echo "zero windows!" && return

local json="["
for (( i=1; i<=$wincount; i++)); do
    json="$json""["
    local cmd="osascript -e 'tell application \"Google Chrome\" to get number of tabs in window $i'"
    local tabcount=$(eval $cmd)
    for (( j=1; j<=$tabcount; j++)); do
        local cmd="osascript -e 'tell application \"Google Chrome\" to get URL of tab $j of window $i'"
        local url=$(eval $cmd)
        [ $j -eq $tabcount ] && json="$json\"$url\"" || json="$json\"$url\","
   done
   [ $i -eq $wincount ] && json="$json]" || json="$json],"
done
echo "$json]"
}
```

This bash function uses applescript to iterate over all chrome windows and each tab in each window to build a array of arrays json.

I store the json in a local file. i use this to backup my chrome state. this script would be faster if i did the json generation all in applescript.

I have a separate function that loads a json file into chrome.

the advantage of this over chrome-cli would be that applescript (plus basic bash scripting) will pretty much not break with osx upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a tool to extract data from chrome session files for precisely this purpose. https://github.com/lemnos/chrome-session-dump.
Running it like so `chrome-session-dump` will produce a list of tabs (in order) which can subsequently be passed to firefox. E.G `chrome-session-dump|xargs firefox`. You can also obtain the currently open tab via `-active` for processing by external scripts.